# Why converting C# HTTP Request to Java did not work?

Tags: java, c#, http-headers

I am trying to use the Microsoft Custom Vision<sup>[know more](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/services/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/)</sup>. I need to make an HTTP request to send the image to be analyzed. I successfully made a request from C# so I know the information is correct.

However, when I tried to make the same request in Java I received an HTTP 400 error.

> I believe I did not handle the request correctly in Java. Is that true?

Following are the snippets.

#### C#:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Prediction-Key", PredicitionKey);
using (var content = new 
ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
  content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
  response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
  Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

#### Java:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Prediction-Key", predicitionKey);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.getOutputStream().write(data.getData());
connection.connect();

Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Please run Fiddler or Wireshark or another tool to compare the exact requests being submitted by both code samples.

Comment: @mjwills i will do that now, but is the html request in java structured correctly. This being the first time using them i am a bit unsure of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace

```
connection.connect();
```

with

```
connection.getResponseCode();
```

If it still doesn't work, then the headers are the problem.

**Since C# code runs successfully**

The only difference between your C# request and Java one in fiddler is that Java request has two additional headers (Accept, User-Agent).

Try setting them explicitly

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36");
```

If still doesn't work, try removing these two headers or check data you're sending in request body.

Comment: Thanks there was a problem in parsing the data to a byte array.   Aswell as the connect needing to be replaced by getresponseCode